# How do contents of git index evolve during a merge (and what's in the index after a failed merge)?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-index

I have a fuzzy idea of what the `git` index contains as one does `git-add`s and `git-commit`s, but I don't have a clue of what happens to these contents when one does a `git-merge`.  I'm particularly interested in learning what the index holds when a merge fails (e.g. due to some conflict).

Comment: merge and rebase are similar in some points. Maybe you can see what happens by doing `git rebase -i` and replace all `pick` by `edit` and then observe .git modification

Comment: @Asenar: the similarity arises because `rebase` is a series of `cherry-pick` operations internally, and for each cherry-picked commit, git uses the merge machinery to apply the changes implied by that commit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For any given path, there are up to four "version numbers" in the index, numbered 0 (zero) through 3.  I'll call them "slots" as if they were actually there for every entry, and then easily indexed (this makes them easier to think about), although actually extra versions are introduced dynamically only when needed.  These "virtual slots" can be "empty", meaning the file does not exist.

(Actually, once an entry is created in the index, it's marked with a flag bit, `CE_REMOVED`, if needed.  This gets hairy because a whole directory full of files can be marked "removed" and then a file can be created with the name of the previous directory and marked "added".  Let's just pretend we have fixed slots, there-but-empty, instead. :-) )

Slot #0 is the "normal", un-conflicted, all-is-well entry.  It contains a bunch of cache data, the path name, and the blob-ID (the SHA-1) for the file stored in the repository.

When a merge succeeds, it's all "business as usual", so the only special case is a conflicted merge.  A merge is "conflicted" when slots 1, 2, and/or 3 are non-empty.  Skipping over most of the mechanics, what happens is this.  The merge uses the "newest" name for all the slots, and:

- Slot zero is left empty (you can't "commit" until you resolve the conflict, by which time this slot won't be empty anymore unless you really want the file to be removed).
- Slot 1 ("base") is filled with the common ancestor version.  If the file is new (in both revisions), this slot is empty.
- Slot 2 ("ours") is filled with the target (`HEAD`, unless you're manually invoking some of the underlying merge machinery) version.  If the file was removed in `HEAD` / target-of-merge, this slot is empty instead.
- Slot 3 ("theirs") is filled with the being-merged-in version.  If the file was removed in the being-merged-in revision, this slot is empty.

Once you resolve the conflict and "git add", the #0 slot gets filled in with whatever you "add", wiping out the entries in #1 through #3—or, if you "git rm" the conflicted file, the other stage entries are still removed, but now the #0 slot remains empty, which also resolves the conflict.

More concretely, then, suppose you have a common ancestor that has (among others) these two files:

```
gronk
flibby
```

You're on branch `cleanup` and you've renamed `gronk` to `breem`, and edited both that and `flibby`.  You decide to `git merge work`, where they modified `gronk` but did not rename it, and removed `flibby`.  Some other file(s) merged cleanly.

The index will contain three versions of `bleem` and two versions of `flibby`:

```
$ git checkout cleanup
Switched to branch 'cleanup'
$ git merge work
CONFLICT (modify/delete): flibby deleted in work and modified
in HEAD. Version HEAD of flibby left in tree.
Auto-merging bleem
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in bleem
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 4362aba7f3b7abf2da0d0ed558cbf5bc0d12e4b0 1   bleem
100644 49db92a61392e9fd691c4af6e1221f408452a128 2   bleem
100644 04b399c8fe321902ce97a1538248878756678ca2 3   bleem
100644 366b52546711401122b791457793a38c033838dd 1   flibby
100644 6fecb1480f45faaabc31b18c91262d03d3767cde 2   flibby
100644 7129c6edb96d08bb44ca1025eb5ae41d41be8903 0   x.txt
```

You can see the original (base) version of `bleem` with `git show :1:bleem`.  That was called `gronk` in the base version (and in `work` as well, in this case), but now it's called `bleem` because git believes you renamed `gronk` to `bleem` in `cleanup`.  (Git finds the renames between the merge-base and `HEAD` and then applies the same renaming to `work` if necessary, as in this case.)

Likewise, you can see the `work` version with `git show :3:bleem` or `git show work:gronk`, and the `HEAD` version with any of: `git show HEAD:bleem`, `git show cleanup:bleem`, or `git show :2:bleem` (slot 2 contains the `HEAD` aka `cleanup` version, and is named according to the name in `HEAD`).

For `flibby`, though, since it was removed in `work`, there is no "theirs" (slot 3) version.

To resolve the conflicts, you need only tell `git add` or `git rm` to update the slot-zero entry and remove the 1-through-3 entries.  Of course, with `git add`, what goes *into* slot 0 is whatever is in the work directory now, so you generally have to edit the files first.

Incidentally, I labeled slots 2 and 3 "ours" and "theirs" above.  This is how `git checkout` treats them as well (`git checkout --ours` and `git checkout --theirs` let you write version 2 or 3 into slot 0; such a checkout, like most checkouts, "erases" the other slots too, thus resolving the conflict).  However, in a rebase, the `HEAD` branch is actually the branch being rebased-on-to, and the "theirs" version is your branch-being-rebased.  So the ours/theirs terminology is not really that great, in my opinion: it's too easy to get it backwards during a rebase.

I should also note that `git checkout -m` will "re-create" a merge conflict, if you're in the middle of a conflicted merge, by erasing slot 0 and "resurrecting" the versions in slots 1-3 as needed (and writing the conflicted merge file to the working directory, obeying any change in your `merge.conflictstyle` setting as well).

Comment: This is a very nice answer.